# How to push a whole sequence to redis in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis

I can use `Redis.rpush('key', 1, 2, 3)` to push three elements to redis, but if there is a sequence:

```
seq = [1, 2, 3]

Redis.rpush('key', seq)
```

It will push a 'seq' element to redis but not the three number. Is there any way I can push the whole sequence to redis?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Redis.rpush('key', *seq)
```

More at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters).